# Disallow NFS parent directory sharing, how?

Tags: linux, mount, nfs

I have `/etc/exports` like this:

```
/data/mydir1 *(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
/data/mydir2 *(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

From clients, I saw I can mount `ip_of_nfsserver:/` or `ip_of_nfsserver:/data` and see all of its sub-directories there, how can I restrict clients can only mount sub-directories defined in `/etc/exports`?

Comment: Are `/data/mydir1` and `/data/mydir2` mountpoints or regular directories?

Comment: @grawity They are actual directories on the nfs server.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're explicitly disabling those checks – that's what `no_subtree_check` does. Switch it back to `subtree_check`. (Pay attention to the performance notes in the exports(5) manual page, though.)

Comment: It doesn't work, I can still mount / or /data after change no_subtree_check to subtree_check...